# How can I map multiple classes (same entity but with augmented properties) to same database table?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a multi-module project where each module defines its own entities. the main program scans the assemblies representing the modules to fetch the `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` for each entity ( via `modelBuidler.LoadFromAssembly()` ).

**Scenario :**

entity `Product` from `module1` is mapped to table `products`

entity `WarehouseProduct` which **inherits** from `Product` (defined above) and add some other properties related to warehousing and is mapped to the **same table** `products`.

*both entities represent the same object* it's just a matter of creating some *bounded contexts* each giving access to relevant properties only !

**Problem :**

I can't figure out how to do that !! DbContext (when trying to create the database) complains that both classes can't share the same table !

**Note**:

both classes `Product` and `WarehouseProduct` have a common ancestor which groups the common properties.

**Edit 1 :**

even trying to map the common part as a ComplexType didn't work, DbContext complains that both entities `Product` and `WarehouseProduct` are not in the same type hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used *contextualized* ( I don't event know if that word exists ;) ) DbMigrations  configurations ( each configuration specific to a single module and with distinct `ContextKey`) to solve my problem.